# Change the color of the obstacle box via MoveIt Python binding

Tags: moveit, python

I'm using the MoveIt Python binding to add obstacles to the scene with

```
move_group = moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander(group_name)
scene.add_box(box_name, box_pose, box_size)
```

The color of all added obstacles is green by default, which is hard to distinguish when there are a lot of obstacles. Is there any way to change the color of some objects individually? For now, I haven't found a way to do this with the Moveit Python binding.

Thanks!